# Cisco device chooses link with higher cost as the root

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree

[image: my topology]

The problem is that psw11 (SG350-28P) is choosing the path to sw10 (C2960L-48TS-LL) with a cost of 20000 as the root instead of the path to sw56 (C2960L-48TS-LL) with a cost of 10000, even though the Arista is the root switch. What could be wrong? Why is this happening?

```
Spanning tree enabled mode MSTP
Default port cost method:  long
The IST ROOT is the CST ROOT
Path Cost   30000
gi24      enabled  128.24    20000    Frw    Root No       P2P Intr          
Po1       enabled  128.1000  10000    Blk    Altn No       P2P Intr
```

The running config of psw11:

```
v2.4.5.71 / RTESLA2.4.5_930_181_144
CLI v1.0
file SSD indicator encrypted
@
ssd-control-start
ssd config
ssd file passphrase control unrestricted
no ssd file integrity control

!
!
unit-type-control-start
unit-type unit 1 network gi uplink none
unit-type-control-end
!
no cdp run
spanning-tree mode mst
spanning-tree loopback-guard
spanning-tree mst configuration
name ust
exit
vlan database
vlan 5,29,32,34,38,60,90,130,140,160,165,169-170,175,180,190,210,220
vlan 222,225,230,240,250,260,290,300,310,320,330,340,350,400,666,777
exit
voice vlan id 5
voice vlan oui-table add 0001e3 Siemens_AG_phone________
voice vlan oui-table add 00036b Cisco_phone_____________
voice vlan oui-table add 00096e Avaya___________________
voice vlan oui-table add 000fe2 H3C_Aolynk______________
voice vlan oui-table add 0060b9 Philips_and_NEC_AG_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00d01e Pingtel_phone___________
voice vlan oui-table add 00e075 Polycom/Veritel_phone___
voice vlan oui-table add 00e0bb 3Com_phone______________
port-channel load-balance src-dst-mac-ip
no eee enable
no ip routing
no bonjour enable

no pnp enable
!

!
interface GigabitEthernet24
 description sw10
 ip dhcp snooping trust
 no spanning-tree portfast
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet25
 description sw56
 channel-group 1 mode auto
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet26
 description sw56
 channel-group 1 mode auto
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet27
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet28
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Port-Channel1
 description sw56
 switchport mode trunk
!
exit
macro auto disabled
```

This one from sw10:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 27684 bytes
!

!
version 15.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec

!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
no logging console
!

system mtu routing 1500
ip arp inspection log-buffer entries 5
ip arp inspection log-buffer logs 1 interval 30
!
!
no ip dhcp snooping information option
no ip domain-lookup

vtp mode transparent
!

!
spanning-tree mode mst
spanning-tree extend system-id
spanning-tree pathcost method long
!
spanning-tree mst configuration
 name ust
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!

no cdp run
!
lldp run
!

!
interface Port-channel1
 description sw251-distrib
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport block multicast
 ip arp inspection trust
 load-interval 30
!
interface Port-channel2
 description psw11
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport block multicast
 ip arp inspection trust
!

!
interface GigabitEthernet0/47
 description psw11
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport block multicast
 ip arp inspection trust
 load-interval 30
 no cdp enable
 ip dhcp snooping trust
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/48
 description psw11
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport block multicast
 ip arp inspection trust
 load-interval 30
 no cdp enable
 ip dhcp snooping trust
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/49
 description sw251-distr
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport block multicast
 ip arp inspection trust
 channel-group 1 mode active
 ip dhcp snooping trust
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/50
 description sw251-distr
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport block multicast
 ip arp inspection trust
 channel-group 1 mode active
 ip dhcp snooping trust
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/51
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/52
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
```

I must point out that when I shut down the link between psw11 and sw10, psw11 starts to work through sw56 and shows a path cost of 20,000. When I turn the link back on, psw11 starts to work through sw10 and shows a path cost of 30,000. Additionally, I would like to include the 'sh spanning-tree' output for psw11:

```
Spanning tree enabled mode MSTP
Default port cost method:  long
Loopback guard:   Enabled


Gathering information ..........
###### MST 0 Vlans Mapped: 1,5,29,32,34,38,60,90,130,140,160,165,169-170,175,180,190,210,220,222,225,230,240,250,260,290,300,310,320,330,340,350,400,666,777
CST Root ID    Priority    0
               Address     c0:bc:9a:af:e0:f0
               The IST ROOT is the CST ROOT
               Root Port   gi24
               Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
IST Master ID  Priority    0
               Address     c0:bc:9a:af:e0:f0
               Path Cost   30000
               Rem hops    18 
Bridge ID      Priority    32768
               Address     70:18:a7:44:57:b6
               Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
               Max hops    20 
  Name     State   Prio.Nbr    Cost    Sts   Role PortFast       Type        
--------- -------- --------- -------- ------ ---- -------- ----------------- 
gi1       enabled  128.1     200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi2       enabled  128.2     2000000  Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
gi3       enabled  128.3     200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi4       enabled  128.4     200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi5       enabled  128.5     200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi6       enabled  128.6     200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi7       enabled  128.7     200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi8       enabled  128.8     200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi9       enabled  128.9     200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi10      enabled  128.10    200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi11      enabled  128.11    200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi12      enabled  128.12    2000000  Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
gi13      enabled  128.13    2000000  Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
gi14      enabled  128.14    2000000  Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
gi15      enabled  128.15    20000    Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi16      enabled  128.16    20000    Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi17      enabled  128.17    2000000  Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
gi18      enabled  128.18    2000000  Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
gi19      enabled  128.19    200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi20      enabled  128.20    200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi21      enabled  128.21    200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi22      enabled  128.22    200000   Frw    Desg Yes      P2P Intr          
gi23      enabled  128.23    2000000  Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
gi24      enabled  128.24    20000    Frw    Root No       P2P Intr          
gi27      enabled  128.27    2000000  Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
gi28      enabled  128.28    2000000  Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
Po1       enabled  128.1000  10000    Blk    Altn No       P2P Intr          
Po2       enabled  128.1001  20000    Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
Po3       enabled  128.1002  20000    Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
Po4       enabled  128.1003  20000    Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
Po5       enabled  128.1004  20000    Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
Po6       enabled  128.1005  20000    Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
Po7       enabled  128.1006  20000    Dsbl   Dsbl No       -                 
Po8       enabled  128.1007  20000    Dsbl   Dsbl No       -
```

on the sw10:

```
MST0
  Spanning tree enabled protocol mstp
  Root ID    Priority    0
             Address     c0bc.9aaf.e0f0
             Cost        0
             Port        456 (Port-channel1)
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32768  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 0)
             Address     548a.ba75.c200
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi0/2               Desg FWD 20000     128.2    P2p Edge 
Gi0/3               Desg FWD 20000     128.3    P2p Edge 
Gi0/4               Desg FWD 20000     128.4    P2p Edge 
Gi0/5               Desg FWD 20000     128.5    P2p Edge 
Gi0/9               Desg FWD 200000    128.9    P2p Edge 
Gi0/10              Desg FWD 20000     128.10   P2p Edge 
Gi0/12              Desg FWD 20000     128.12   P2p Edge 
Gi0/22              Desg FWD 20000     128.22   P2p Edge 
Gi0/23              Desg FWD 20000     128.23   P2p Edge 
Gi0/24              Desg FWD 20000     128.24   P2p Edge 
Gi0/25              Desg FWD 20000     128.25   P2p Edge 
Gi0/26              Desg FWD 20000     128.26   P2p Edge 
Gi0/29              Desg FWD 20000     128.29   P2p Edge 
Gi0/33              Desg FWD 20000     128.33   P2p Edge 
Gi0/35              Desg FWD 20000     128.35   P2p Edge 
Gi0/36              Desg FWD 200000    128.36   P2p Edge 
Gi0/37              Desg FWD 20000     128.37   P2p Edge 
Gi0/38              Desg FWD 20000     128.38   P2p Edge 
Gi0/39              Desg FWD 20000     128.39   P2p Edge 
Gi0/41              Desg FWD 200000    128.41   P2p Edge 
Gi0/46              Desg FWD 200000    128.46   P2p Edge 
Gi0/48              Desg FWD 20000     128.48   P2p 
Po1                 Root FWD 10000     128.456  P2p
```

and on the sw56 too:

```
MST0
  Spanning tree enabled protocol mstp
  Root ID    Priority    0
             Address     c0bc.9aaf.e0f0
             Cost        0
             Port        456 (Port-channel1)
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32768  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 0)
             Address     548a.ba76.6880
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi0/1               Desg FWD 200000    128.1    P2p Edge 
Gi0/3               Desg FWD 200000    128.3    P2p Edge 
Gi0/5               Desg FWD 200000    128.5    P2p Edge 
Gi0/6               Desg FWD 200000    128.6    P2p Edge 
Gi0/7               Desg FWD 200000    128.7    P2p Edge 
Gi0/9               Desg FWD 200000    128.9    P2p Edge 
Gi0/10              Desg FWD 20000     128.10   P2p Edge 
Gi0/11              Desg FWD 200000    128.11   P2p Edge 
Gi0/12              Desg FWD 20000     128.12   P2p Edge 
Gi0/13              Desg FWD 200000    128.13   P2p Edge 
Gi0/15              Desg FWD 200000    128.15   P2p Edge 
Gi0/17              Desg FWD 200000    128.17   P2p Edge 
Gi0/19              Desg FWD 200000    128.19   P2p Edge 
Gi0/21              Desg FWD 200000    128.21   P2p Edge 
Gi0/23              Desg FWD 200000    128.23   P2p Edge 
Gi0/36              Desg FWD 200000    128.36   Shr Edge 
Gi0/37              Desg FWD 2000000   128.37   Shr Edge 
Gi0/38              Desg FWD 20000     128.38   P2p Edge 
Gi0/39              Desg FWD 2000000   128.39   Shr Edge 
Gi0/40              Desg FWD 20000     128.40   P2p 
Gi0/41              Desg FWD 2000000   128.41   Shr Edge 
Gi0/42              Desg FWD 20000     128.42   P2p Edge 
Gi0/44              Desg FWD 20000     128.44   P2p Edge 
Po1                 Root FWD 10000     128.456  P2p 
Po2                 Desg FWD 10000     128.464  P2p
```

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. Please edit your question to include the output of `show running-config` of the psw11.

Comment: Also sw10.  It appears the priority of the interface has been changed.

Comment: As it seems, the (high) VPC interface index is considered before the link cost...

Comment: I thought the vPC interface is a type of single EtherChannel between two devices, but neither sw10, psw11, nor sw56 are stacked devices. However, sw251 or Arista are stacked.